# camelContext error : INFO : `No credentials available for NTLM <any realm>@myProxyHostUrl.com:8080`

Tags: java, apache-camel

[image]I want to call a rest API at http://anyPublicWebsite.url.com via camel. This connection needs proxy host to be configured over the network. I have configured the camelContext as follows :

```
public class CamelTester {
    static {
        camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
        camelContext.getProperties().put("http.proxyAuthMethod", "Basic");
        camelContext.getProperties().put("http.proxyAuthUsername", "usernameForproxy");
        camelContext.getProperties().put("http.proxyAuthPassword", "passwordforProxy");
        camelContext.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "myProxyHostUrl.com");
        camelContext.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "8080");
        try {
            camelContext.addRoutes(new SpringRouteBuilder() {
                @Override
                public void configure() throws Exception {
                    from("direct:starthttp").to("http://anyPublicWebsite.url.com").end();
                }
            });
            camelContext.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and then accessing it via

```
camelContext.createProducerTemplate().sendBody("direct:starthttp", ExchangePattern.InOut,"");
```

Upon starting this program , below mentioned error has occurred

```
Aug 23, 2017 4:50:38 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthChallengeProcessor selectAuthScheme
INFO: ntlm authentication scheme selected
Aug 23, 2017 4:50:38 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector processProxyAuthChallenge
INFO: No credentials available for NTLM <any realm>@myProxyHostUrl.com:8080
```

I'm wondering why camel is not able to capture the provided username and password for proxyAuth?

***Note**: These proxy settings are working at other places like cmd,eclipse IDE, maven settings etc..

Comment: That is not how you add properties to camel. Please check the documentation for how to do that.Check the http4 component for the properties to add on the endpoint to configure your proxy.

Comment: @souciance-eqdam-rashti  please have a look at the above edit, camel-doc itself specifies this method of adding properties in Java DSL

Comment: Why don't you just use camel-http4 and use the properties sent on the endpoint instead?

Comment: I would look at http://camel.apache.org/properties.html to see how properties are used in Camel.

Comment: @souciance-eqdam-rashti problem is sorted when I used "to("http4://webUrl.com?proxyAuthHost=proxyHost&proxyAuthPort=8080&proxyAuthUsername=username&proxyAuthPassword=pwd")" with http4 component, but still wondering why it is not working with http

Comment: camel-http is based on an older apache http client. I would only use http4 for standard http calls..and when adding properties either add them on the endpoint or via the properties component..